# Drawing a wedge in ARKit using SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to draw a wedge of a circle using UIBezierPath, but when drawing it it shows a triangle and instead of drawing a curve through my points, it draws a straight line.

I am constructing the SCNNode Like so:

```
let path = UiBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint.zero, radius: 0.5, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi/2, clockwise: true)
path.close()

let shape = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: 0.1)
let mat = SCNMaterial()
mat.diffuse.contents = UIColor.orange
shape.materials = [mat]

let node = SCNNode(geometry: shape)
```

When I position this node in the world, and add it to the scene it draws a triangle. How can I make it so there is a curve instead of just a straight line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the flatness of the path to 0 fixed this issue:
`path.flatness = 0`